# switching rebalance protocol in apache kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to kafka and encounter a tricky issue in the production environment.

Here's the situation: I have multiple instances of a service consuming(in a same consumer group) messages from a topic on a kafka cluster(v2.4). Those instances use the default "EAGER" rebalance protocol. Now I need to switch to the incremental cooperative sticky protocol by upgrading and redeploying those consumer instances.

My question: Is it possible to switch to the new protocol without stopping the full kafka cluster? If yes, how?

My naive thoughts: I assume the two protocols won't work together for the same consumer group, right? So I should stop the whole kafka cluster and the whole consumer group to do the upgrade